How to correctly define and handle a static JSON array in WireMock Handlebars extension?
I'm using WireMock's standalone version with Handlebars for creating dynamic responses. I need to include a static JSON array in the JWT payload. However, when I try to define the array in the mapping file, it's treated as a string rather than a JSON array.
Here is a simple example of my configuration:
Request:
{
  "request": {
    "method": "GET",
    "urlPath": "/api/test"
  },
  "response": {
    "status": 200,
    "body": "{{{jwt 
        userId='12345'
        userName='testUser'
        myArray='[{\"key1\":\"value1\"}, {\"key2\":\"value2\"}]'
        isActive=true
        role='admin'
    }}}"
  }
}

Expected Output:
{
  "userId": "12345",
  "userName": "testUser",
  "myArray": [
    {"key1": "value1"},
    {"key2": "value2"}
  ],
  "isActive": true,
  "role": "admin"
}

The array myArray is being treated as a string, not as a JSON object array. How can I define and handle a static JSON array correctly in WireMock Handlebars to be recognized as a JSON array, not a string?

At the moment this is not possible.  Arrays within the jwt plugin can only be of type Integer, Long or String and not objects like you are trying to achieve.
Because you have the single quote around the value for myArray it is being treated as a string like you mentioned in your question.  You can pass an array as the value and it will be treated like an array instead:
{{{jwt userId='12345' userName='testUser' myArray=(array 1 2 3) isActive=true role='admin'}}}

Once decoded, the jwt that is returned looks like this:
{
  "userId": "12345",
  "userName": "testUser",
  "myArray": [
    1,
    2,
    3
  ],
  "isActive": true,
  "role": "admin"
}

As I mentioned above, only certain types are allowed in the array so it is a little limited.
